# Can't compile with runtime dependency, but can with compile

Tags: java, maven, okta

I have a multi-module project, in one module I'm trying to add [Okta-SDK](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java) dependency as described in the README:

```xml
<properties>
  <okta.version>1.5.4</okta.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-api</artifactId>
    <version>${okta.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${okta.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>${okta.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't compile with `mvn clean package -pl my-module`, it fails with error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /some/path/OktaUsers.java:[9,38] error: package com.okta.sdk.impl.resource.user does not exist
[ERROR] /some/path/OktaUsers.java:[96,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class OktaUsers
/some/path/OktaUsers.java:[97,13] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 3 errors
```

This class `OktaUsers` has references to Okta-SDK classes. But if I change `runtime` scope to `compile` for `okta-sdk-impl` artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${okta.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then compiling finished fine: `mvn clean package -pl my-module`:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But final app is not working as expected because of dependency issues:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore
    at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.AbstractClient.createDataStore(AbstractClient.java:73)
    at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.AbstractClient.<init>(AbstractClient.java:68)
    at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClient.<init>(DefaultClient.java:99)
    at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClientBuilder.build(DefaultClientBuilder.java:305)
```

I thought all dependencies with `runtime` scope should be available when compiling. But it seems that doesn't. How can I fix this issue? I need to have this dependency for compiling and for runtime both.

---

UPDATE:

I can't share sources from this project, since it's private, but here some lines from `OktaUser` class:

```java
import com.okta.sdk.client.Client;
import com.okta.sdk.impl.resource.user.DefaultRole;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.group.Group;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.group.GroupBuilder;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.user.Role;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.user.RoleStatus;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.user.UserBuilder;
import com.okta.sdk.resource.user.UserProfile;


public final class OktaUsers implements Users {

    private final Client okta;


// line 95:
    private Role adminRole() {
        final DefaultRole role =
            (DefaultRole) this.okta.instantiate(Role.class);
        role.setProperty("type", "USER_ADMIN");
        role.setProperty("status", RoleStatus.ACTIVE);
        return role;
    }
}
```

I'm using classes from `impl` dependency here, since `api` dep doesn't have methods to manage Okta roles.

---

This code works fine with integration tests when running `mvn verify -pl my-module`

---

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T22:00:29+03:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven-bin-3.6
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: IcedTea, runtime: /opt/icedtea-bin-3.12.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.44-gentoo", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK? It looks like you have a missed matched version of okta-sdk. Make sure they are all on the same version and you should be good to go! –

Comment: @KunalVohra I've a property `okta.version` with version in `pom.xml` to set all versions in one place, the version is `1.5.4`

Comment: can you share broader details of your project like its springboot, maven etc. I have dont integration recently but haven't followed your mentioned approach. It is very easy to implement. May be otherway around would work for you.

Comment: @KunalVohra I added Maven version details to the question, the're no spring dependencies at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the content of `/some/path/OktaUsers.java`? It looks like this class is depending on classes from the Okta IMPL package. If I understand the Okta API correctly your own code is supposed to depend on/use only classes from the API module, NOT the impl modules. If you remove the dependency on the class from the impl module you should be fine.

**Edit 1:**
I see two approaches. You could remove the dependency to DefaultRole.

```
// line 95:
private Role adminRole() {
    Role role = this.okta.instantiate(Role.class);
    role.setType("USER_ADMIN");
    // use reflection to check if there is a setProperty() method
    // and call it if it's really necessary
    // role.setProperty("status", RoleStatus.ACTIVE);
    return role;
}
```

The second approach is to find out, why the jvm cannot instantiate `com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore`. This can be a very tedious task as the jvm doesn't dive you a proper error message. I'd guess that a dependency is missing from the classpath. You need to look at the source of the class and make sure that all referenced classes (and all classes referenced by these classes and so on) are on the classpath. Doing so, you need to make sure that the correct versions of these classes are used, i.e. the same versions that the referencing classes were build against. For starters, make sure that `org.slf4j.Logger` and a single implementation of the logger is on the classpath and that it's properly configured.

The proper fix would be to change the api. There seems to be a solved [issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java/issues/249) in the okta issue list describing a similar problem. Maybe this can help you? If not, I suggest contacting the okta developer and asking them how to fix your problem.

Comment: You're right, I'm using some classes from `impl` dependency (updated the question with some sources). But this code works fine with integration tests when running with `mvn verify -pl my-module`

Answer (score 1):

A dependency with scope `runtime` is available at runtime only, not at compile time. This is meant for implementation jars and framework jars that should not be called directly.

A dependency with scope `compile` is available both at compile time and at runtime.